# Jenkins fails when building with parameter to select build number

Tags: jenkins, nullpointerexception

In Jenkins have a build job (QA_BUILD) and a deploy job (QA_DEPLOY). The QA_DEPLOY job was originally set to deploy the latest stable build and it worked fine. Now I have set it up to be a parameterized job where I can actually choose the build number of the QA_BUILD job I want to deploy, but it gives me this error:

```
    ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1035)
    at hudson.plugins.copyartifact.BuildSelectorParameter.getSelectorFromXml(BuildSelectorParameter.java:87)
    at hudson.plugins.copyartifact.ParameterizedBuildSelector.getBuild(ParameterizedBuildSelector.java:52)
    at hudson.plugins.copyartifact.CopyArtifact.perform(CopyArtifact.java:354)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:75)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1744)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Build step 'Copy artifacts from another project' marked build as failure
```

This is how the deploy job is set up:

I checked off "This build is parameterized"

I chose "Build selector for Copy Artifact" and I gave it name "BuildSelector"

In the dropdown for Default Selector     I picked "specific build"

Later on in the BUILD steps, I chose "Copy artifacts from another project"

For "Project name" I chose "QA_BUILD" which is the build job.
For "which build" I chose "specified by build parameter" in the dropdown, then I refer to the parameter I created above, "${BuildSelector}"

This variable ${BuildSelector} is what breaks the deploy job. If I hardcode an existing build number it builds. How do I get this to work as a parameter I can set? It looks like I did everything properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Parameter Name" field in the "Copy artifacts from another project" subsection of the "Build" section of the QA_DEPLOY job, specify "BuildSelector" rather than "${BuildSelector}".

Comment: I answered my own question above but will give you the points. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I should have used BuildSelector not ${BuildSelector}. Problem solved.